# How to Convert Friendly URLs to contain only Reference Code

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, friendly-url

I would like to convert (or add from the beginning) all products' Friendly URLs to their "Reference Codes" (without any id or code), eg;

www.shopname.com/main-category/sub-category/referance-code-of-product

and convert (or add from the beginning) all product categories' Friendly URLs to their "Category Names" (without any id or code), eg;

www.shopname.com/main-category/sub-category/...

Is there any way to do that with hack (or maybe with an Addon)? Thanks.

Comment: There used to be an addon for that in PrestaShop 1.3, but I'm afraid it doesn't work anymore since 1.4. I know that this doesn't help much, but you could always try to find it and start from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search 'Advanced URL' on the official addons market of PrestaShop. It's a good starting point and makes part of what you want.

Otherwise you have to override the Dispatcher class, the ProductController class and the CategoryController class, but it might be very difficult if you're not prepared enough :)